# How to send a ejs file as HTML email from nodejs application as cronjob

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, nodemailer

I have a node.js app and I want to send a HTML email from this application daily at 8AM to few people. I have a dashboard.ejs file that gets some data from the database and shows them in a bootstrap dashboard template. I want to send this dashboard.ejs as an HTML email with all the datas from the database and the styling same as when this dashboard.ejs is loaded from the application.

I have the cron job ready and the mailer function ready. All I am unable to do is send the dashboard.ejs file as HTML via email.Can this be done? If yes, any help would be appreciated.

```
var mailer = require('express-mailer');
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
mailer.extend(app, {
    from: 'user@gmailcom',
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    secureConnection: true;
    port: 465, // port for secure SMTP
    transportMethod: 'SMTP',
    auth: {
        user: 'user@gmail.com',
        pass: 'password'
    }
});

var job = new CronJob('00 49 * * * *', function() {
        console.log('This runs on 49th second of every min every hour every day every month every year')
        app.mailer.send('dashboards/dashboard', {
            to: 'user2@gmail.com',
            subject: 'TEST EMAIL',
            message:'Hello World'
            }, 
            function(err) {
                if(err)
                    console.log('ERROR', err);
            }
        );
    },
    function() {
        console.log('This function is executed when job stops');
    },
    false,
    'Asia/Kolkata'
);
job.start();
```

Answer (score 5):

Unless you're building this into an already existing express app then I would discourage this approach. You're not really using express in the above example for anything more than the view engines.

Instead of using Express, just take the part you need and use it. You can use `ejs` directly to generate the html with the data using [`ejs.renderFile()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs#usage). Then use [`nodemailer`](https://nodemailer.com/) to send the e-mail (which `express-mail` uses to send e-mails for you).

```
const ejs = require('ejs');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const template = './dashboards/dashboard.ejs';

const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'user@gmail.com',
    pass: '*'
  }
});

const job = new CronJob('00 49 * * * *', function() {
    let templateData = {
      name: 'Test Name'
    };

    ejs.renderFile(template, templateData, (err, html) => {
      if (err) console.log(err); // Handle error

      console.log(`HTML: ${html}`);

      let mailOpts = {
        from: 'user@gmail.com',
        to: 'recipient',
        subject: 'EJS Test File',
        html: html
      };

     transport.sendMail(mailOpts, (err, info) => {
       if (err) console.log(err); //Handle Error

       console.log(info);
     });
    });
  }, () => { 
    console.log('This function is executed when job stops'); 
  },
  false,
  'Asia/Kolkata'
};

job.start();
```

Comment: Thanks @peteb. I am completely new to node.js and I have no idea about the framework or working. Thanks for your valueable info and guidance. I will implement this way and let you know if it works.

Comment: Your method worked like a charm, but I also need to get the css and images in my email too. Have you got any clue on how to embed images/css into this mail?

Comment: @BiswarupDass For image embed you can convert them to base64 strings and send them that way.

Comment: @DevShadow You shouldn't embed images in an e-mail, you should link to them. Embedded images can cause an e-mail to get flagged as junk or malware.

Comment: For the CSS you should use inline styles.